# Prove that $ |f(x)| \leq ||f'||_{L^2} \sqrt{x (1 -x)} $ for any $f$ in $W_0^{1,2} ([0, 1])$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I need to prove that $\forall x \in [0, 1]$ and $\forall f \in W_0^{1,2} ([0, 1])$, the following inequality

$$ |f(x)| \leq ||f'||_{L^2} \sqrt{x (1 -x)} $$

holds true.

The same inequality with $\sqrt{x}$ can be easily shown with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I wasn't able to generalise the proof for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The estimate $|f(x)| \le \sqrt{1-x} \|f'\|_{L^2}$ can be proved just as easily. The idea then is to combine both estimates to squeeze out a little more. Here is how this is done:

We have $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t) dt = \int_x^1 (-f'(t)) dt$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, to be chosen later, and set
$$
I_\alpha(t) = \begin{cases} \alpha \; (0 \le t \le x) \\ \alpha - 1 \; (x < t \le 1) \end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
f(x) = \alpha \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt + (1 - \alpha) \int_x^1 (-f'(t)) dt = \int_0^1 f'(t) I_\alpha(t) dt
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|f(x)| \le \|f'\|_{L^2} \|I_\alpha\|_{L^2} = \|f'\|_{L^2} \sqrt{\alpha^2 x + (1 - \alpha)^2(1-x)} \, . 
$$
Now set $\alpha = 1-x$ and the estimate follows.